# Is beeswax ok to use to keep a screw tight?

Tags: repair, screws, wooden-furniture, self-assembly-furniture

I have purchased a table and chair set, and the screws holding it together consistently come loose (from pulling and dragging I assume).  I have heard that beeswax will help hold things together, and wanted to verify before I went down the process of unscrewing all the chairs and coating with wax, and screwing back in.

Any tips?

Comment: Is the material that holds the screws metal or wood?

Comment: I believe it's metal inserts in the wood.

Comment: The legs are held with screws, or with nuts and bolts? The couple tables I can remember assembling (including the one in my kitchen right now) has a bolt sticking out of the table that goes through a hole in the leg, which is then held on with a wingnut. If you don't know what I mean, perhaps you can take a picture of the connection under the table.

Comment: No,  unfortunately.  The holes are on the legs,  and the screw goes in from the outside.

Comment: Beeswax, unless really cold is a lubricant, good for drawer slides, dipping wood screw threads so they won't bind . Now propolis in the other hand is tacky, has resin content and can harden to the point that it needs extra work with the hive tool to break the supers apart. But you'll have to be a beekeeper to get the good stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is beeswax ok to use to keep a screw tight?

No, bees wax is a [lubricant](http://www.screwwax.com/) - it makes it easier, not harder, for screws to be removed.

Comment: Bummer - I must have heard wrong - but thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Wax will help make it easier to insert a screw (especially into wood) but I've never heard of it helping hold a screw.

I think what you want in your case is a product known as Thread Lock (Brand name: Loctite). This is essentially a glue that you apply to the threads. If you've ever taken apart something and noticed a blue (usually) substance on the threads, you've already encountered this product. It comes in a few different variants (usually differentiated by color) depending the strength you need and how likely you are to remove the screw.

See this manufacture for an example: [Loctite Threadlockers](http://www.henkelna.com/industrial/blue-threadlockers-medium-strength-13231.htm).

*I have no association with this product.*

Comment: I've heard of this - but hoping for something less chemically based. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @KellyJAndrews then try white glue, or whatever glue you're comfortable with.

Comment: If you're unwilling to pay for Loctite, fingernail polish on the threads can also be quite effective.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger - in the aviation industry, this is known as torque seal or anti-sabotage lacquer. I remember opening up Japanese radios and seeing a little dot on every screw head and nut. It did two things, showed that something had been disassembled and had just enough integrity to prevent small fasteners from coming undone.

Comment: Best to use Loctite, Blue can allow easy disassembly, Red is semi-permanent and Yellow will never come apart unless you apply heat.

Comment: While I appreciate the opinions, I've not really seen anyone actually answer the question, just give me alternatives.